# Spring Boot Admin - Polling duration changes not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

Based on latest version of spring boot admin (https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/), we can configure the polling duration (in ms) to fetch the data.

The default for this is 2500 ms and I have updated it to 250000 ms.
However, the data is still being fetched at 2500 ms frequency.

My application.properties looks like :

```
server.port=8000
spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
server.forward-headers-strategy=native
spring.boot.admin.monitor.status-interval=150000
spring.boot.admin.monitor.status-lifetime=150000
spring.boot.admin.monitor.info-interval=300000
spring.boot.admin.monitor.info-lifetime=300000
spring.boot.admin.ui.poll-timer.process=250000
spring.boot.admin.ui.poll-timer.memory=250000
spring.boot.admin.ui.poll-timer.gc=250000
```

The four spring.boot.admin.monitor.* settings work fine, but the three settings for spring.boot.admin.ui.poll-timer.* are not reflecting and the default value is being used.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Have you set this in the client or the spring boot admin server?